# Sum of the previous elements in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a array

```
[3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0]
```

For each element of the array, I need the sum of its previous elements.

I know how get the previous element but not all the previous elements.

```
last = mytab[index - 1] //change here 
res = (e + last) / (index + 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate with `each_with_object`

numbers = [3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 6.0, 10.0]

```
sum_of_repvious = numbers.each_with_object([]) do |number, accu|
  previous = accu.last || 0 # on the first iteration, there is no previous, initialize to 0
  accu << previous += number
end

p sum_of_repvious #> [3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 13.0, 19.0, 29.0]
```

Let me explain a bit more in detail what is going on here:

With `each_with_object` you iterate the array and have an additional object that is passed to each iteration. I chose it to be an empty array (the `[]`).

I call this **accumlator** or **accu** for short.

In this array i store the sum of the previous numbers. On the first step, there is no previous sum, hence the `|| 0` to make sure that we have `0` instead of `nil`.

Now you have an array that has the sum of the numbers in your original array up to the respective index.

Comment: `numbers.each_with_object([0.0]) { |number, accu| accu << accu.last += number }` ?

Comment: @mudasobwa i had this solution first. but it shifts the indexes so i went for the nil check.

Comment: `numbers.each_with_object([0.0]) { |number, accu| accu << accu.last += number }.drop(1)` if you care about indices.

Comment: @mudasobwa I know. But I prefer this solution over the other one. I added a comment to explain why the `|| 0` is there though.

Answer (score 3):

```
def sum_array_of_last_elements(array)
  array.reduce([]) { |memo, itm| memo << itm.to_f + memo.last.to_f }
end
```

Comment: no need to call `to_f` on the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

for Simple and easy way try **[Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)**

```
> sum = 0
> a.map{|x| sum += x}
#=> [3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 13.0, 19.0, 29.0]
```

**Note:** As per experts this is not good practice, just alternate solution

Comment: Dumb local variable declared upfront is a code smell.

Comment: @mudasobwa: I find this code much easier to read than the accepted answer.

Comment: The block `a.map` is that way producing side effects, which is a bad practice in general. Also, local variables, specifically used as closure parameters, are GC’ed worse and might in some cases lead to memory leaks in MRI. I did not say, BTW, that is wrong; I said it is a code smell. I personally don’t like when my code looks like PHP.

Comment: I found that you do not understand the difference between blocks and lambdas. Also, I did not introduce anything there, I answered the question about passing _local variable_ to closure.

Comment: @mudasobwa : updated answer with note

Comment: Please, don’t get me wrong: I am not an expert by any means and I never insisted on setting my point of view: I am just sharing it.

Comment: yes I appreciate and always welcome new ideas and good suggestions for self improvements  :)